# how to get user online status with socket.io & nodeJS immediately

Tags: node.js, socket.io

socket.io has a setting 'close timeout' 60s and so there is a delay about 75 seconds from user closed the webpage to trigger the event 'disconnect'(so I know he was offline).It's too long for me..what I want is a very quick response to know a user ONLINE STATUS CHANGED.I use a interval ajax get method on front-end so I know wether a user is online and if timeout he if offline , but I think it's a awful design and there must be some way better then this,will you guys help me?thx very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of socket.io do you use ? 
I never see `disconnect` event fired after more than 1s.

Comment: 0.97, I start a stopwatch when I close the tab,and it's 75 secs util the 'disconnect' event triggered on the server side.what's you version?

Comment: Mine is 1.0x now, but even with 0.9x branch, i never face that. New version is available so give it a try.

Comment: bingo!I changed the socket.io to 1.0.6 and it works perfect!thank you very much!